# angular 5 reactive forms, disable validation

Tags: angular, validation

Currently I have a `input type="text"` with ReactiveForms.
Angular always adds `ng-xxx` css classes (e.g. `ng-valid`)

I'd like to disable this all together (I know I can just change the appropriate css classes)

Is it possible to disable validation completley (including css etc.) for a single input field?

see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fjmyzc for an example

Comment: You probably didn't save your stackblitz, the link got me to the default angular project example.

Comment: sorry, saved it now

Comment: btw, it is almost just the default angular project. I only added an input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using FormControls than the **ng-xxxx** classes will apply to form elements as they are the core building block of the form control to work with form element on the DOM. 
I don't know why you want to disable these classes but if you are not using them you should ignore them, all these classes are optional and doesn't contains any styling on their own and to differentiate it as angular styling these are prefixed with "**ng**"